# Iptables issue error at line 2

Tags: iptables

I messed up with my ip table now i am facking some kind of issue with that iptables to start.Below content is present in my iptables file. But when i try to start the ip tables i am facing error as below

> iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: iptables-restore: un'ble to initialize table 'filter
>
> Error occurred at line: 2 Try `iptables-restore -h' or
>   'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Oct 28 04:59:26 2015

    *filter
    :INPUT DROP [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [65:8794]
    :fail2ban-MAIL - [0:0]
    :fail2ban-SSH - [0:0]
    :fail2ban-VESTA - [0:0]
    :vesta - [0:0]
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3333 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8083 -j fail2ban-VESTA 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,2525,110,995,143,993 -j fail2ban-MAIL 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j fail2ban-SSH 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,12000:12100 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,2525 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,995 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 143,993 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3306,5432 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8083 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 10.15.0.5/32 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 188.166.241.106/32 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 143 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 5432 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8433 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8083 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 12000:12100 -j ACCEPT 
    -A fail2ban-MAIL -j RETURN 
    -A fail2ban-SSH -s 190.95.191.67/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
    -A fail2ban-SSH -j RETURN 
    -A fail2ban-VESTA -j RETURN 
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Wed Oct 28 04:59:26 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your kernel recently?
Check if you have filter module enabled:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko
```